# Three.js: Applying matrix to group of objects and then updating their locations

Tags: javascript, three.js

When we add objects from a scene to a group(now Object3D()), how do we apply the correct matrix for the group objects, so their locations would get updated in the scene.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as far as I know -by default ; object automatically update their matrices if they have been added to the scene with

```
var object = new THREE.Object3D();

scene.add( object );
```

if they are the child of another object that has been added to the scene:

```
var object1 = new THREE.Object3D();
var object2 = new THREE.Object3D();

object1.add( object2 );
scene.add( object1 );

 //object1 and object2 will automatically update their matrices
```

There is more [here](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/How-to-update-things)